# How do I install Windows 10 ONTO a USB drive?

Tags: usb, installation, windows-10

I have a USB, with Ubuntu installed into it, and I have a USB with android-x86 installed onto it. I was just wondering, is there any way to install Windows 10 onto a USB drive?

Please note, unlike many questions on the internet right now, I'm NOT asking how to create a bootable installer USB, to use to install Windows 10. What I'm after, is how to install Windows 10, onto the USB drive.

I have tried, and my USB doesn't show up in the list of available devices... Do I need to format my USB to NTFS first, in order for the Windows 10 installer to recognize it as a possible install location? Or does it only recongise attached hard drives/solid state drives? Or is there some way to make it work?

This is a fresh install of Windows 10, not an update. I have already created installation media.

Comment: Sorry, but like I said in my question, I don't want know how to make an installer USB, I want to know if there's a way to install the actual operating system, to my USB. I've already used Rufus to make the installation media.

Comment: [How to create a Windows To Go USB drive running Windows 10](http://www.winbeta.org/news/create-windows-go-usb-drive-running-windows-10)

Comment: Do you want something similar to WindowsToGo?

Comment: I suppose so, but is it possible to install on a non-certified USB? Is there any way to change the USB from "Removable" to "Fixed", so Windows will accept as a to-go drive. Is it possible to install onto drive smaller than 32GB?

Comment: http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Putting-Windows-8-on-a-USB-Drive